# How to use WHERE clause in mongodb when the key of a field is numeric

Tags: mongodb, shell, where-clause

Say I insert a document into mongo like below:

```
db.test.insert({1 : { 2 : "some value"}, 3 : { 4 :"some other value"}});
```

How do I use the $where clause to match this document? I tried using the following:

```
db.test.find({"$where" : "this.1.2 == this.3.4"});
```

but I ended up getting this error message.

```
    error: {
    "$err" : "JavaScript execution failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected number",
    "code" : 16722
    }
```

I know $where is not recommended, but say if I have to use it, is there any way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: JS this object should also accept array accession: `this['1'] `

Comment: @Sammaye that works, but what if "1" is nested inside another object. say for example {a : {1 : "some value"}}. this.a['1'] doesn't seem to work in that case. Thanks by the way!

Comment: Possibly if your question explains **"why"** you have to use it, what you are actually doing, and what your data actually looks like. Then you can get real answers. Consider editing your question with this detail.